# dialog --inputbox

Tags: bash, dialog

Follow the below script I've a unique variable that keeps all variables, I need have each variable separated from `$VALUES`:

```
#!/bin/bash
shell=""
groups=""
user=""
home=""
exec 3>&1
VALUES=$(dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
          --backtitle "Linux User Managment" \
          --title "Useradd" \
          --form "Create a new user" \
15 50 0 \
        "Username:" 1 1 "$user"         1 10 10 0 \
        "Shell:"    2 1 "$shell"        2 10 15 0 \
        "Group:"    3 1 "$groups"       3 10 8 0 \
        "HOME:"     4 1 "$home"         4 10 40 0 \
2>&1 1>&3)
exec 3>&-

echo "$VALUES"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
shell=""
groups=""
user=""
home=""
exec 3>&1
dialog --separate-widget $'\n' --ok-label "Submit" \
          --backtitle "Linux User Managment" \
          --title "Useradd" \
          --form "Create a new user" \
15 50 0 \
        "Username:" 1 1 "$user"         1 10 10 0 \
        "Shell:"    2 1 "$shell"        2 10 15 0 \
        "Group:"    3 1 "$groups"       3 10 8 0 \
        "HOME:"     4 1 "$home"         4 10 40 0 \
2>&1 1>&3 | {
  read -r user
  read -r shell
  read -r groups
  read -r home

  echo $user
  echo $shell
  echo $groups
  echo $home

  #continue script here
}
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how I can control "return" key of keyboard so when I press it, cursor goes to next line?